# When I try to input a double it doesn't let me use periods, only commas

Tags: java.util.scanner

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
double a = in.nextDouble();
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

When I try to use a period in the input (like 34.4) this error appears, but it works perfectly when I use a comma.

How can I make it work for periods?

Answer (score 2):

Your system is probably set up using a locale that uses commas for decimals.

Force a locale that uses periods in decimals. Try this (make sure you have Locale imported):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);  
double a = in.nextDouble();
```